# Wrong superscript positioning with xelatex and alternative font

Tags: fonts, xetex, mathspec

Trying to change the math font with xelatex, I used the following commands:

```
\usepackage[cm]{sfmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Universalis ADF Std}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin){Universalis ADF Std}
\setmathfont[range="21A6]{latinmodern-math.otf}
```

The relevant one is the `setmathsfont` command.

Now everything works fine, apart from the fact that superscripts are not positioned correctly, i.e. they are too far to the left:

[image]

This happens even if I use font Arial for variables.

Is there a way to get this right?

Answer (score 4):

It's a well known problem with `mathspec`; you have to precede the letter with `"` in order that superscripts are better placed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{sfmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
%\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Universalis ADF Std}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin){Universalis ADF Std}
\setmathfont[range="21A6]{latinmodern-math.otf}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
"f'(x)&=3x^2-4,\\
"f''(x)&=6x,\\
"f'''(x)&=6,\\
"f^{(4)}&=0.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Still the placement is not ideal, though, possibly because the italic correction defined for “f” by the Universalis ADF font is too small.

Comment: Ok, so the easiest solution seems to be building a math version of the font using FontForge. Seems to be not too difficult, managed to get the f right.